# Getting a WriteableDraft error in redux with Type Definition Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am having a type Error which I do not understand

This is the type for the state

```
export type Foo = {
    animals: {
        dogs?: Dogs[],
        cats?: Cats[],
        fishs?: Fishs[]
    },
    animalQueue: (Dogs | Cats | Fishs)[]
}
```

Now, in a reducer I am trying this

```
...
someFunction: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ index: number, animalKey: keyof Required<Foo>['animals']}> => {
    const {index, animalKey} = action.payload
    const animal = state.animalQueue[index]
    state.animals[animalKey]!.push(animal)
}
...
```

Now this gives me the error

> TS2345: Argument of type 'WritableDraft | WritableDraft | WritableDraft<...>  is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dogs & Cats & Fishs. Type 'WritableDraft' is not assignable to type 'Dogs & Cats & Fishs'. Property 'height' is missing in type 'WritableDraft' but required in type 'Cats'.

I assume this is because of this

```
(Dogs | Cats | Fishs)[]
```

So what I try to define here is an Array that can contain `Dogs` and/or `Cats` and/or `Fishs`. So basically everything in an 'mixed' amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tight type checking is needed

```
someFunction: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ index: number, animalKey: keyof Required<Foo>['animals'] }>) => {
    const { index, animalKey } = action.payload;
    const animal = state.animalQueue[index];
    switch (animalKey):
        case 'dogs':
            if(isDogType(animal)) state.animals[animalKey]!.push(animal as Dogs);
            break;
        case 'cats':
            if(isCatType(animal)) state.animals[animalKey]!.push(animal as Cats);
            break;
        case 'fishs':
            if(isFishType(animal)) state.animals[animalKey]!.push(animal as Fishs);
            break;
}
```

where `isDogType()`, `isCatType()` and `isFishType()` are [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thе еrror you'rе еncountеring is duе to TypеScript's typе chеcking and how it's intеracting with thе typеs you'vе dеfinеd for your Foo statе.  It's rеlatеd to thе fact that TypеScript is trying to еnsurе that thе typеs match corrеctly whеn you'rе pushing еlеmеnts into thе animals array basеd on thе animalKеy.

Thе еrror mеssagе indicatеs that TypеScript is еxpеcting a cеrtain sеt of propеrtiеs (such as 'hеight' for Cats) that arе not prеsеnt in thе WritablеDraft typе you'rе using.

Here is your updated reducer function:

```
someFunction: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ index: number, animalKey: keyof Required<Foo>['animals'] }>) => {
    const { index, animalKey } = action.payload;
    const animal = state.animalQueue[index];

    if (animalKey === 'dogs') {
        state.animals.dogs!.push(animal as Dogs);
    } else if (animalKey === 'cats') {
        state.animals.cats!.push(animal as Cats);
    } else if (animalKey === 'fishs') {
        state.animals.fishs!.push(animal as Fishs);
    }
}
```